# PHP - scope perseverance - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, scope

My question stems from a model I am writing to construct queries from predefined search objects that contain 'criteria', each search has a property `$search->criteria` that is an array of criteria objects....

```
Criteria (

    "name"    => "name",  //name of given field to be searched
    "expr"    => "expr",  //could be "<=" ">=" "="
    "s_value" => "value"  //value to be searched with

)
```

and the part of my search function that is adding the proper where statements to the query...

```
    if(count($criteria)) {
        foreach($criteria as $crit) {
            $this->{$crit['name']}($crit['s_value'],$crit['expr']);
        }
    }
```

And now finally the function that loop is calling, 'name' here corresponds with whatever the criteria object has set as $criteria['name']....

```
function name($value,$expr = '=') {              

    $this->db->where('specific_field_name '.$expr,$value);

}
```

Now for the question..

I want to create a variable inside 'name' that will persist beyond a single execution, so for instance, if I have 2 criteria with the same name and it executes twice, I want to maintain a variable in it's scope for multiple executions.

**EDIT**

What I *WANT* to do.  **I have multple functions like this that all need their own counters.**

```
function name($value,$expr = '=') {              
    if(isset($count))        
        $this->db->or_where('specific_field_name '.$expr,$value);
        $count++;
    }
    else {
        $count = 1;
        $this->db->where('specific_field_name '.$expr,$value);
    }
}
```

Ideas?

**SOLUTION**

```
    if(count($criteria)) {
        $criteria_count = array()
        foreach($criteria as $crit) {
            if(isset($criteria_count[$crit['name']])) {
                $criteria_count[$crit['name']]++;
            }
            else {
                $criteria_count[$crit['name']] = 1;
            }
            $this->{$crit['name']}($crit['s_value'],$crit['expr'],$criteria_count[$crit['name']]);
        }
    }
```

Changed the main search function to maintain a `$criteria_count` array with the names as keys and passing the count down to the specific functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `global` statement if you really want to do it this way.

Edit: here is how I might pass count into name and keep track of it that way.

At beginning of search function: `$count = 0;`

```
if(count($criteria)) {
        foreach($criteria as $crit) {
            $count = $this->{$crit['name']}($crit['s_value'],$crit['expr'],$count);
        }
    }
```

And then the name function:

```
function name($value,$expr = '=',$count) {              
    if($count > 0)        
        $this->db->or_where('specific_field_name '.$expr,$value);
        $count++;
    }
    else {
        $count = 1;
        $this->db->where('specific_field_name '.$expr,$value);
    }
return $count;
}
```

Comment: I'll edit the question to point out why a global variable wouldn't meet my need.

Comment: How about passing in count and returning it?

Comment: "I have multple functions like this that all need their own counters."

Comment: Hmm. How about a count array and each function uses a different key?

Comment: That actually the solution I was implementing as you made that comment, thanks for getting me thinking in that direction.